# How do I subtract 1 from an array item in BASH?

Tags: bash

I have a side-project in BASH for fun, and I have this code snippet (`ARRAY[0]` is 8):

```
while [ $ALIVE == true ]; do
    $ARRAY[0] = ${ARRAY[0]} - 1
    echo ${ARRAY[0]}
done
```

However, it comes back with this error:

```
line 16: 8[1]: command not found
```

I just started working in BASH, so I might be making an obvious mistake, but I've searched and searched for an answer to a problem like this and came up with no result.

Comment: You're not allowed to have a space around the `=` in **any** assignment in bash. This isn't specific to arrays at all.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ will find this and other errors for you.

Comment: ...and just as good-practice notes -- all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved by POSIX specification for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: (and `==` isn't a standard string comparison operator inside `[ ]` -- that's just a single `=`. Bash supports `==` as an extension, but that'll bite you when someone tries to run your code with `/bin/sh` on a platform using ash or dash; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html. Quoting to avoid bugs, and changing the variable names, that would make that first line `while [ "$alive" = true ]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest change is simply:

```
ARRAY[0]=$(( ${ARRAY[0]} - 1 ))
```

Note:

- No `$` before the name of the variable to assign to (`foo=`, not `$foo=`)
- No spaces around the `=` on the assignment
- `$(( ))` is the syntax to enter a math context (and expand to the result of that operation).

Comment: I believe the smallest version of this would be `((ARRAY[0]--))`.  :)

Comment: Sure; I was claiming smallest edit distance, not shortest code :)